# Display an specific array from a Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the Schema I'm using:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

  user: String,
  pass: String,
  imagen: [{ 

              title: String,
              name: String,
              description: String

});
```

And this is what I'm doing:

```
usermodel.find({ 'imagen._id': req.params.id }, function (err, imagen){

  user.imagen 

    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(imagen);

    res.send(imagen);

});
```

What I want to receive it's just the element inside the `imagen` array whit the `_id`I'm looking for, but instead that, I receive the hole schema of the user, whit all his imagens. Is there any what to receive only the array object that I'm looking for? This is an example:

[ { __v: 3,
    _id: 50f41ccff405ef73c4000006,
    pass: 'mangakas123',
    user: 'kirbo',
    imagen: 
     [
       { title: 'DQ monstes',
         name: 'DragonQuest1and2EnemySpriteGallery_02.png',
         description: 'A compilation of DQ monsters',
         _id: 50f41f868e7f9919c7000006 } ],
    timeline: [],
    notification: [],
    followers: [ '50f41c8c59ebd50fc4000006' ],
    follow: [] } ]

And I want jus this:

```
[{ title: 'DQ monstes',
     name: 'DragonQuest1and2EnemySpriteGallery_02.png',
     description: 'A compilation of DQ monsters',
     _id: 50f41f868e7f9919c7000006 }]
```

Thank's advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can exclude other fields like this

```
usermodel.find({ 'imagen._id': req.params.id },{'imagen':true}, function (err, imagen){

  user.imagen 

    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(imagen);

    res.send(imagen);

});
```

see the second parameter for find(): http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: It works, but not how I expected. I get the hole `image` array, not only the array element whit the `_id` I'm looking for, and, the console show me this error `Cannot read property '_id' of null` after show the `imagen` array. Why this happens? Mongoose read perfectly the array, and showed it in the console.